# Is it possible to plot a function with a vertical tangent line while the plot of the function has no vertical line segment?

Tags: derivatives

Is it possible to plot a function with a vertical tangent line while the plot of the function has no vertical line segment?

Comment: You should perhaps be a bit more careful with your choice of words. A "derivate" or a "function" cannot *be* a "line", those are different concepts. I suspect that what you are asking is whether the **tangent line** to the **graph of a function** can be vertical at a point? (What you mean by the function itself being a vertical line, or a step function having vertical slope, I don't know, however...)

Comment: Valid point. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, eg- x^(1/3) (real to real only not complex) and has a vertical tangent at x=0

Comment: If I take the derivative of the function, I get a function with $x$ in the denominator. I think that would make the derivative undefined at $x=0$, but I am not absolutely sure.

Comment: Yes the derivative is undefined, but you yourself asked for it right?

Comment: I didn't get ur question, is you want a "vertical deravite" then it has to be undefined...

Comment: Point taken, maybe the only way to get a vertical slope is to have an undefined slope...

Comment: Hmm is there any other way, I'm just curious if you know pl tell me

Comment: I don't think there is. Slope is defined as rise/run.